# What does “choper” mean?

Tags: sens, argot

I have come across a word a number of times during  conversations but I am still some what lost in its translation. The word sounds something like *choper* or *chouper*. The problem is that I don't know  if I heard it right or spelled it right but I am sure it sounds 90 % similar.

The context was somewhat wierd — we were talking about girls, discos and all those manly stuffs that guys talk about ;)

Along similar lines what exactly does *kiffer* mean? If it means same as *aimer*, a little insight into its origin and normal usage is appreciated.

Edit: I think as all have pointed out it is actually *choper* and not *choupé*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*[Kiffer](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/kiffer)* is a slang word for *aimer* (to like). Apparently it comes from the Moroccan Arabic word *kif* (كيف), meaning hashish (another Arabic word, meaning "grass" or "hay"). The semantic link between the Arabic word and the French slang term is that hashish provides pleasant feelings. Therefore a *kif* (used as a noun) is a pleasant experience, and *kiffer* means to like something or find it pleasant.

Regarding "choupé", I've never heard of it but you might have actually heard the verb [*choper*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/choper). It is a familiar word meaning "to catch", and in the same context and slang language level as *kiffer*, it might mean "managing to get in a relationship with someone". An English word with a somwhat similar meaning and usage is *score*, though *choper* is less strong, it does not imply any specific act, it can be as short as a single kiss.

Both words are slang words, mainly used by teenagers and young adults.

Comment: Thanks :) Can choper replace the verb attraper to some extent ? Can you please construct a sentence incorporating the two in one or separately in order to have an example ?

Comment: @Geekasaur *Choper* means catch or steal, but it cannot replace *attraper* in normal usage.

Comment: @Gilles I quite disagree. In `choper un rhume`, `choper un train`, and generally `choper quelque chose au vol`, `choper` can be replaced by `attraper`.

Comment: @AlexisPigeon True, I should have said that it cannot replace *attraper* everywhere.

Answer (score 8):

"*Choper*" is usually a synonym of "*prendre*".

> The context was somewhat weird — we were talking about girls, discos and all those manly stuffs that guys talk about ;)

In this context, it likely means "have a sexual relationship with [the girl]".

Comment: *Choper* does not necessarily mean to have a sexual relationship. It may involve kissing only. It is very dependent on the habits of the micro-society in which it is used...